# Lion kills application behind the scene, how to put application on a do not kill list?

Tags: macos

I am encountering an irritating feature of Lion.

Say I spend 30 minutes in XCode, then I go to iChat to talk to my girlfriend for 5 minutes, then I switch to Safari to check StackExchange, gmail, and whatever else I might want to check.

Then I switch to Safari where I run another set of pages. For 5 or 10 seconds, the app resumes with beachball. This is annoying as hell (switch appnames around, they behave the same).

How can I prevent this from happening at all (unlikely) or at least mitigate it by making a list of apps that are not allowed to go into silently-killed mode?

Comment: [Is there a way to disable OS X auto termination of applications?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/48780/8546) (2012-04-16)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. Check out [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3233318?start=0&tstart=0) on the Apple discussion forum. You can also read [this article](http://www.tuaw.com/2011/08/09/lions-ios-like-automatic-termination-not-ideal-for-some-users/) from TUAW.

Comment: I must say, this sucks hard. I've been pushing many people to Apple because I believe it's a more productive environment, but killing apps is very annoying, and "but it's fast enough that you won't feel it" is not true: people notice it... and post here ;)

Comment: @Kheldar I haven't actually updated to Lion yet, but I have done some "research" (reading posts here) and have found things like what you have posted about. I am a superuser on my computer and I like to be able to control _*everything*_. :-) Lion has several things that you can't turn off.

Comment: One thing I have noticed about this "feature" is that it boosts the incentives to have an SSD application drive. It used to be "how often are you really launching applications?" was a valid counter-argument to the fast launching of an SSD. Now the answer is "all the damned time".